# Unable to construct JSON for strategy matrix from a variable

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions

I wish to use a variable `$unique_envList` from `CONTRUCT_UPLOAD_ZIP` job as a strategy matrix for another job `upload-to`.

Note: `$unique_envList = @()` and is constructed inside a loop like `$unique_envList += $item`.

However, the strategy does not show in GitHub Actions workflow for the job `upload-to`.

I get the following error:

> Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'upload-to'. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 33, Col: 18): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 33, Col: 18): Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.,.github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 33, Col: 18): Unexpected value ''

I also tried `echo "newgenmatrix=$newmatrix" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"` but it did not help either.

I also tried `$newmatrix = $unique_envList | ConvertTo-Json`

What is the issue with my approach?

```yaml
name: Your Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  CONSTRUCT_UPLOAD_ZIP:
    outputs:
      NEWENV-MATRIX: ${{ steps.newmatrixtask.outputs.newgenmatrix }}

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Construct new zip per environment
        id: newmatrixtask
        run: |
          $envList = "item1_pom item2 item3_xml item4_txt"         
          $envList = $envList -split ''

          $unique_envList = @()
          foreach ($item in $envList) {
            if ($item -like "*_*") {
              $item = ($item -split "_")[0]
              $unique_envList += $item
            }
          }

          # I now wish to construct strategy matrix json type of  $unique_envList. Below attempt does not help. 

          foreach ($item in $unique_envList) {
            Write-Host "NEW ENV LIST: $item"
          }
          $newmatrix = "[" + $unique_envList.Replace(' ', ', ') + "]"
          echo "newgenmatrix=$newmatrix" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"

  upload-to:
    needs: CONSTRUCT_UPLOAD_ZIP
    runs-on: windows-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        envName: ${{fromJson(needs.CONSTRUCT_UPLOAD_ZIP.outputs.NEWENV-MATRIX)}}

    steps:
      - name: Upload to JFrog
        run: |
          echo "Uploading for the environment: ${{ matrix.envName }}"
```

I want the strategy to run thrice with the following items:

```
item1
item3
item4
```

Comment: Have you verified the generated JSON? Is that valid? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Looks like it should be: `$newmatrix = '["' + $unique_envList.Replace(' ', '","') + '"]'`

Comment: You need a two step authentication.  Step one is to get token.  Step 2 is to send token with request.  The error says you are missing the token.

Comment: @Azeem tried your suggestion but I got all elements of the matrix as a single element like `item1 item2 item3'. Thus, instead of running thrice it just runs a single time.

Comment: @jdweng The issue is with constructing a good format for the strategy matrix and not to do with token although the error says so.

Comment: @Ashar: That was a suggestion given the sample in your question. Your generated matrix is not a valid JSON. You need to fix that. With a valid JSON, you won't get the parse error.

Comment: @Azeem that's what i m struggling to construct :D

Comment: Most Systems are moving from Windows Credentials to a two step authentication (like OAUTH2) so code will run on Windows, Linux, and MAC.  What strategy matrix?  You do not have any control over what the OS is going (or using) for credentials.  You have to use what the OS is using.  Microsoft developed CORE so same code will work on Windows, Linux, or MAC without changes.  CORE rewrote the low level OS interface to be common for all OS.

Comment: @Ashar: You need to update your question with your exact scenario. In your description, you mentioned that it's an array but in your sample workflow you're using a string literal. You can simply print your generated matrix in the same job in the next step and figure out where's the issue in the JSON using a linter e.g. https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: @Azeem I updated the original post to show exactly how `$unique_envList` is constructed. I tried to validate the workflow but it seems to give an irrelevant error at line 1 i.e `name: Your Workflow` which is inline the same indentation as `on` and `jobs`. Kindly suggest.

Comment: @Ashar: That error is due to the comment. That comment needs to be indented properly under its respective multiline string.

Comment: @Ashar: Check [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJx9kstugzAQRfd8xRVCIqQy6muFRFQ1iz5UqV2QVVUhGpzELdgU20mqNP9eMITQJOoGzXjmnvHgK3iAQsuF9SHeZWABeaJKtq4jQGhVaCWbpCvB2WwgFS2kP6ecNKd+2+s3KbZbIyo1l0RUM1aMp2IlSZYoKpWpGcSOTcDSAHtee2wIAX66FHAoXz4xqRDCZormF3EhctTRpflexes8M9F1rNbKBpFFxhRcuH2K5uxL03gPuxl4vfpMlDSZLjBwGBjvhnrY9JoANjMdJGOfFO4wHrqHHcejzsJG014rdr3X87c/mq11OnbanxtiLPiSlioS5FEKfjSCjEVelFTKnphOFwJ2Qwhbko3RCHa9XHD3EN1PbuPnSfQyiWyrEuoiE0naPBCnNJUBem/z/8uWVTL/PjBOd5l6nnHRrBR5vcDA8P2TVvJ2XjrwizGGWcqtUa22Qlf97i9qStKo).

Comment: You are still getting the same error.  All the changes you made are just cosmetic and not changing the root cause of the error.  The real issue is you do not have a TOKEN.  Where are you getting the TOKEN?  The changes you are making may be valid and are needed.  But the changes are not correct the real error.

Comment: @Azeem it worked seems `Compress` did the trick however I m not sure why and how. Can you post as answer?

Comment: @Ashar: Without `-Compress`, `ConvertTo-Json` generates multiline JSON. To accommodate that you'll have to set it as a multiline output parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to convert the complete list to JSON array. In addition to replacing spaces with commas, you'll need to quote the values as well (double quotes). However, using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.2) does this automatically.

Here's a working solution with `ConvertTo-Json`:

```
$envList = "item1_pom item2 item3_xml item4_txt" -split ' '

$unique_envList = @()
foreach ($i in $envList) {
  if ($i -like '*_*') {
    $unique_envList += ($i -split '_')[0]
  }
}

$matrix = ConvertTo-Json $unique_envList -Compress
echo "matrix=$matrix" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

Observe the use of [`-Compress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.2#-compress) flag to create the compact JSON. Without it, you'll have to [set it as a multiline output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter).